# Fetching UIImage from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a `Core Data` to save a UIImage that i get from my `UIImagePickerController` (source type = image library). I then Place or rather want to place the photo in a `UICollectionViewCell`, Please help and check to see what I am doing wrong.

Here is my `UIImagePickerController` it is called by a delegate.

```
-(void)requestAddScreen {
_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.allowsEditing = NO;
_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Screen" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Screen* newScreen = [[Screen alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
newScreen.image = imageData;
[_project addProjectScreensObject:newScreen];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];



if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:_picker completion:^{
[_collectionView reloadData];
}];  
}
```

And Here is my ViewWillAppear meted. this is where I fetch the data from Core Data, id it Correct?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:nil];
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

//load project
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", @"EMO-KIT"];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
if (array.count == 1) {
    _project = array[0];
} else {
    _project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [_project   setValue:@"EMO-KIT" forKey:@"name"];
}
NSArray* screens = [[_project projectScreens] array];
NSIndexPath *bottomIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:screens.count inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: bottomIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: You can store the image in directory and store the path in coredata.

Comment: *"Please help and check to see what I am doing wrong."* What problem(s) are you having that you need help with?

Comment: Well I want to know if the coding im doing will successfully save the picture that my UIImagePicker picks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert UIImage to NSData and save into Core Data as below

Saving

```
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[newsObj setValue:imageData forKey:@"Image"];
```

Retrieving

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[screenObj valueForKey:@"Image"]];
```

Hope it helps you..